# Unable to Access MongoDB Atlas from API hosted on Cpanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cpanel, mongodb-atlas

I need to prototype a simple Node.js REST API hosted on a Cpanel server that connects to a MongoDB Atlas cluster using the following connection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://auser:apassword@cluster0-6bnnw.gcp.mongodb.net/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})
```

The Node.js API is running just fine as I can carry out basic requests to it, but anything to do with the DB ends with it hanging and returning the error:

**'Incomplete response received from application'**

Checking the CPanel logs show me the following errors:

```
App 106656 output:     at TLSSocket.err (.../skylab/11/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
App 106656 output:     at callback (.../skylab/11/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
App 106656 output:     at makeConnection (.../skylab/11/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7)
App 106656 output:     at connect (.../skylab/11/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1008:9)
```

When testing:

- Testing from a local Node.js app to a local mongoDB instance works.
- Testing from a local Node.js app to the mongoDB cluster works.

I have whitelisted connections to the cluster within atlas (giving it 0.0.0.0).

I can also access the mongoDB cluster with the above connection string from Studio 3T without issue.

Comment: I think you need to whitelist the actual IP Address of the Cpanel server. Can you try doing that? Add the IP Address of the CPanel server to the list of whitelisted API and see if it works

Comment: Hey could you make it work? Facing the same issue

Comment: @Zak unfortunately I never got this to work- given time I might give this another shot one day and update the question.